# One vhost, multiple certificates

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4, subdomain

I have the domain example.com with the subdomains : www.example.com and a.example.com. Let's suppose that I can't buy a wildcard certificate but, I bought the certificates for example.com and www.example.com. Now I bought the certificate for a.example.com. The site and it's subdomains are in the same folder, using one Apache vhost file and subdomains are defined as aliases.

1. Can I merge the certificates into one file ?
2. What if I used the same key, csr files to generate the certificates ?
3. Is the **ONLY** solution to declare the sites in two different vhosts ?

Comment: My scenario is similar, default virtualhost can be branded, e.g. `www.cust1.brand.com` and `www.cust2.brand.com`, main site is on `www.main.com` (as well as `www.brand.com`, `brand.com` and `legacy.example.com`) and `main.com`... (Code looks at `Host` header to brand site) Tens of identical VirtualHosts seems impractical to maintain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I merge the certificates into one file?

No, only one leaf certificate is supported.  Although from version 2.4.8 the [`SSLCertificateFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) directive allows multiple certificates in that file, that is only to include intermediate CA certificates, sorted from leaf to root, as a replacement for the [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) directive.

The [`SSLCertificateFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) directive can be used multiple times (referencing different filenames) when an RSA, a DSA, and an ECC based server certificate is used in parallel. But you can't use multiple `SSLCertificateFile` directives to load a certificate for the `ServerName` and an extra for the ServerAlias.

> What if I used the same key, csr files to generate the certificates?

Still no.

> Is the ONLY solution to declare the sites in two different vhosts ?

If you have two certificates you need two SSL VirtualHosts.

Answer (score 1):

Can't merge certificates. But you can do it other way.
For Apache, you can use [mod_macro](https://www.cri.ensmp.fr/%7Ecoelho/mod_macro/).

I've got 50 domains (like a.com, b.com, c.com, d.com, etc) based on the same wordpress code directory. While convert to https, every domain has its own certificate and private key files. I don't want to copy & paste & change the VirtualHost block codes for 50 times.

By mod_macro I don't need to do the VirtualHost block 50 times.

I've answered in another similar question: [Is it possible to generate a variable for SSLCertificateFile from HTTP_HOST (or something similar)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095421/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-variable-for-sslcertificatefile-from-http-host-or/)